# Xcode 5.0.1 iOS 7.0.3 Error with instruments command line tool

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I have consistently getting the following error message when trying to launch `UIAutomation` test with the instruments `command line tool`:

> 2013-10-30 12:08:47.868 ScriptAgent[4687:2e07] CLTilesManagerClient:
>   initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
>
> 2013-10-30 12:08:47.869 ScriptAgent[4687:2e07] CLTilesManagerClient:
>   init 2013-10-30 12:08:47.869 ScriptAgent[4687:2e07]
>   CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0xa5b0aa0 2013-10-30 12:09:17.989
>   ScriptAgent[4687:2e07] +[UIAXElement initializeAccessibility]:
>   UIAutomation never received kAXAccessibilityLoaded.  Waited 30.02
>   seconds. 2013-10-30 12:09:17.990 ScriptAgent[4687:2e07] AXError: Could
>   not auto-register for pid status change 2013-10-30 12:09:18.008
>   ScriptAgent[4687:2e07] **Failed to enable accessiblity,
>   kAXErrorServerNotFound** 2013-10-30 12:09:18.381
>   instruments[4633:240f] Automation Instrument ran into an exception
>   while trying to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException
>   2013-10-30 11:09:18 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run
>   the script.

Anyone else have this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo rm /tmp/instruments_sock` -- this is the socket file created by instruments.js to communicate with instruments. That file is probably not deleateable for some reason.

That command will delete the file. Alternatively try to change the permission settings for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this issue on Xcode 5.0.1, instruments doesn't work even start from UI
but instruments works fine with Xcode 5.0

After some investigation, I found that when instruments is starting, the scriptAgent in iPhoneSimulator SDK crashes.

```
Process:         ScriptAgent [4297]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/ScriptAgent
Identifier:      ScriptAgent
Version:         270
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  instruments [4208]
Responsible:     eclipse [1017]
User ID:         110125050

Date/Time:       2013-11-11 10:52:49.044 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  A496DC68-476F-589B-352C-303FA1CD2355

Sleep/Wake UUID: F65E37D7-0AFF-4867-9538-8736C8F0B908

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator (external launch) , iPhone OS 7.0.3 (unknown/11B508)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x02e94952 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x02e58167 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x02b6ae12 abort + 127
3   ScreenReaderCore                0x03db5853 SCRCUncaughtExceptionHandler + 111
4   CoreFoundation                  0x005f7a1d __handleUncaughtException + 749
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0224ab5c _objc_terminate() + 100
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x02a5bf60 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x02a5b97d __cxa_throw + 116
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0224a9cd objc_exception_throw + 323
9   CoreFoundation                  0x005673bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
10  UIAutomation                    0x00cbdf54 +[UIAXElement initializeAccessibility] +    668
11  UIAutomation                    0x00cc1361 +[UIAXElement uiaxSystemWideElement] + 37
12  UIAutomation                    0x00cd76d3 -[UIATarget init] + 317
13  UIAutomation                    0x00cd758a +[UIATarget localTarget] + 65
14  ScriptAgent                     0x0000ae25 0x1000 + 40485
15  ScriptAgent                     0x00005e85 0x1000 + 20101
16  ScriptAgent                     0x00008887 0x1000 + 30855
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x02d5e70d start + 1
```

So I replaced iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk with the one in Xcode 5.0, then this issue is solved.
But I am not sure whether this replacement has any side effect.